# Looping through Datastore query results takes too long. Is there a way to speed this up?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am querying the datastore that looks something like this:

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.gqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY,
                                    "SELECT * FROM " + kind
                                            + " WHERE Location = place").build();
results = datastore.run(query);
```

The results are being stored in a `QueryResults<Entity> results;`

Then I loop through the results and extract the data I need.

The kind has around 10000 Entities in it and I am extracting them all.

```
while (results.hasNext()) {

   Entity result = results.next(); 
   ....
}
```

Is takes 10-ish seconds for this to happen. Is there a way to reduce this time? I know that looping through results is causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Make sure you set the batch size to 500 when you run your query. By default, it's 10.

(b) Optimize your own code inside the loop. For example:

```
Entity result;

while (results.hasNext()) {
   result = results.next(); 
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Where do I set the batch size?

Comment: In low-level Datastore API there is FetchOptions object that you can pass when preparing a query. I don't see a similar option in Gcloud API - it may be a good question to ask the Gcloud team.

Comment: Check if you can switch to the Datastore API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/api-overview) - it is optimized for App Engine, and I find it to be very fast.